# How can I mass produce steel without coal?

Tags: internal-consistency, economy, chemistry, industrial-age

So, Suppose for a moment that there is a society on the verge of an industrial revolution.

They live on a super-continent. The continent has a circumference of around 40,000 kilometers (If I recall correctly), and while the interior is almost entirely desert, there are habitable areas on the edge, including a few large forests.

They have plentiful iron ore and limestone, but due to their world's history, very little coal.

What they do have a lot of is crude oil; Even before the industrial revolution, the people invented specialized lamps and stoves that burn crude oil, and their medieval alchemists spent a lot of time working on refining it for better use.

This post provides a pretty good example of the steelmaking process we use here on earth: [How would fantasy dwarves produce steel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73605/how-would-fantasy-dwarves-produce-steel)

coal coke is a very vital part of that operation.

So... How would these people go about making all of the steel they'll need to power their industrial revolution? Can they find a way to substitute crude oil for coal in the above process, or do they need a novel way to mass produce steel? Or, are they forced to rely entirely on charcoal for the process?

Comment: You can turn coal into oil and oil into coal it just takes more coal or oil. Charcoal is also a thing. There are a number of questions on here about this already.

Comment: The [Hybrit initiative](https://www.ssab.com/company/sustainability/sustainable-operations/hybrit) is a attempt to create fossil-free steel (without the use of coking coal). Instead hydrogen and electricity is used. Not that it would be possible for a pre-industrial society but still a really cool project.

Comment: Our normal way to make steel is to use coal as both fuel and carbon source for the steel, then burn off the excess carbon (and other impurities). When using a hydrocarbon fuel for heat, you can get away with using a *lot* less coal, but still need some as ingredient for the steel. use charcoal for that, and the crucible method in that answer down below.

Comment: First paragraph begins with "So...", last paragraph begins with "So...". Does that make this a "so-so question"?

Comment: Steel can be made without using carbon as a reducing agent. Hydrogen can be used instead. A range of other reducing agents could also be used, but are not for financial reasons
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/iron-ore-reduction

Comment: What's wrong with charcoal.

Comment: Charcoal is in limited supply in this scenario.

Comment: OK fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Petroleum Coke

They need a lot of oil, but you say they have lots of oil. So they can make coke from petroleum, [petcoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_coke). Its just [a little harder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coker_unit) to do but not prohibitively hard. The process would be available prior to large scale steel production, so no bootstrapping problem.  Note it does produce a LOT more co2 than using coal, like half as much more by weight, so expect a worse greenhouse effect.  You will also be using the oil as fuel so you do need a lot of it. Honestly having that much oil and no coal is not very believable, but that is a different question. If they have several times more oil than what the earth has you will be fine.

Here is an image of the overall process
[image]

And an Image of how the coker specifically works.
[image]

Earlier systems were even simpler.

As a side effect they will have a lot of naphtha, diesel, gasoline, and methane, so they may be using that for steam engine fuel.

Alternatively you can make coke from wood but you need an absurd amount of wood, like more than most countries can produce sustainably. Like amore forest than every other land biome combined.

Comment: The amount of oil you need is dependent on the amount of steel you produce. Unlikely this civilization will be as steel dependent as we are. More likely, with alchemists concentrating on oil, they will have plastics instead.

Comment: ...If I recall correctly, oil burns a little cleaner than coal... would that offset the extra emissions from the coke process?

Comment: @Globin347 as far as greenhouse emissions go oil is no cleaner than coal

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond plastic can't replace steel in most of its usages, most steel (70+%) is used for construction, machinery, and vehicles.

Comment: Note: this process was not invented until the mid-1800s (100+ years into the industrial revolution).   So, this contradicts the on the "verge of an industrial revolution" criteria without a certain amount of hand waving.

Comment: @Nosajimiki not really, the tech was there just not the desire, they didn't need another source of coke, coking petroleum was invented to make liquid fuels. which you really only need once the industrial revolution is on its way.  honestly the process itself could be made with renaissance tech, just not to the needed scale. If you don't care about the liquid fuels you can even use steam distillation for the initial stages.

Answer (score 3):

### Crucible Steel

The main reason for using coal or coke is that it burns in a way that alloys the iron with carbon.  Crude oil does not burn but rather, the vapor coming off of it does, this mean you can not just dunk your iron ore into oil and burn it, because the heat would be above the ore.  Nor is there a good way to burn oil under iron ore in a way that will allow an interchange of the pertrol's carbon with the molten iron.

That said, the sealed crucible steels that you see in the classical to high-medieval periods did not melt the ore inside of the coal/charcoal, instead they mix powered ore and charcoal inside of a crucible, then heated the crucible from the outside.  The fuel can in this case be anything of sufficient heat including burning oil, and the iron will alloy with the carbon from the charcoal to make your carbon steel.

Normally making iron from just charcoal and a high quality iron ore requires about 50-60 parts charcoal and 2 parts iron ore (by weight) to get 1 part refined steel.  So, technically you can make steel using just charcoal, but you would run out of trees very fast trying to mass produce steel this way.  By using the crucible method, you only need a small amount charcoal.  It takes about ~2-3 parts charcoal to 75 parts iron ore (by weight).  And the heat can all be had from what is probably going to be your cheaper source of energy: your oil.

The reason this method was no longer used by the industrial revolution was that it leads to more impurities because impurities normally flow out of a bloom as it heats up, or out of the slag vent of a stack furnace whereas a sealed crucible holds them all together in a way that you need to keep the iron completely molten for a period of time while the impurities separate so they can be broken away.  This means you need a bit more labor than a stack furnace to get an inferior steel. Even when you remove the silicate and oxygen impurities with a sealed crucible, the sulfur and phosphorus are harder to deal with.  For this you need a hot blast mechanism which negates the point of a sealed crucible.

#### Here you have a world building choice:

**A: Mass produce wootz steel**

A dig site in Merv from about 900AD shows us that sealed crucible steel could be produced in large batches by putting many crucibles into a large underground kiln.  This method would not only work for your purposes, but also helps prevent fuel waste since underground kilns retain heat so much better than their above ground varitiety.  While many people claim that the blast furnace was the reason for the steel boom, the much more important factor was actually the invention of better tools for working steel.  Industrial era roller presses, die presses, wire gauges, metal lathes, etc. allowed people to skip the very laborious task of hammering steel into its needed shapes.  Add to this a mechanical hammer for breaking the impurited away from your pucks, and you can produce very large amounts of damascus steel with very little charcoal.  It won't take a temper as well as industrial era steel; so, don't expect as good of impact/vibration resistance or springiness, but it will still suit a wide array of uses.

**B: Substitute coke for charcoal in a stack or bloom furnace.**

Before the 1700s, this is how steel was normally smelted.  While this would be very bad for your forests over any serious length of time, charcoal can absolutely be used in place of coke for mass producing steel.  Traditional tatara furnaces are still used in Japan today to produce batches of steel in excess of 1 ton using only charcoal.  The steel produced by these furnaces produces small amounts of high carbon tamahagane as is used in Katana making, and the rest is sold for making a wide range of mass produced carbon steel products such as kitchen knives.

**C: Jump forward to a more modern steel production method.**

If you want to mass produce industrial era quality steel, you need to do what we do in more modern steel production.  1st begin with crucible steel as described above, but use open crucibles with slag vents that you can hot blast with oxygen until all of the impurities (including the carbon) are removed.  This will create a very soft but pure iron.  Then in the final stage you add your charcoal to the crucible and seal it up to reintroduce the carbon in the final stage of smelting.  This would yield steel that is going to be of a higher quality than the early industrial revolution because you can so much more precisely control for your final carbon content, and it can be made using very little charcoal relying mostly on burning oil.

Another Jump forward solution is to use petcoke as described in John's answer, but this is arguably a harder leap forward since the oil refineries needed to make the stuff are comparatively more complex and difficult to make without an already existing industrial age framework to support its manufacture.

Comment: Coke is used in the smelting of iron ore into pig iron, usually in a blast furnace, crucibles are used to make steel FROM pig iron, Crucibles need already smelted iron to work, using crucibles does not help you mass produce steel without coal. You still need coke to make crucible steel. Also large quantities in this case means enough for the making for swords or armor not enough for a large industrial process.

Comment: @John That is incorrect.  Sealed crucibles were used before pig iron was a thing to make steel directly from ore.  This results in wootz steel (aka:damascus steel) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wootz_steel

Comment: Wootz steel is completely useless for industrial steel. it requires a lot of working and can only be made in very small quantities. The OP is looking for industrial steel, not just swords or armor. you need something cast-able or press-able. .

Comment: @John Wootz steel is caste, not pattern welded as previously thought.  In recent decades, manuscripts have been found explaining the whole process as used in the medieval period and metallurgical testing has been done on actual swords and recreations to confirm. Also, according to a number of research projects conducted by the US government in the early-mid 1800s wootz patterning was a well known side-effect of sulfur and phosphorus contamination.

Comment: Patterned steel was considered acceptable for most uses accept for railroad struts.  For some applications, phosphorus contamination was even considered a good thing.   This all means that it would be acceptable for nearly all early industrial revolution purposes since railroads did not come into play until well into the industrial revolution.

Comment: Sources, please, especially for industrial uses of pattern welded steel, "except struts" means I am willing to bet it was "except for anything under high stress" which is the stuff you needed steel for. Also a source for for Wootz steel being made directly from ore (not made from pig iron) being castable in large quantities.

Comment: Wootz is not pattern welded steel at all.  The patterning is a known side effect of sulfur contamination in crucible steel.  It will take me a while to re-find all my sources since it would mean back-tracking research that I did last year over the course of a few weeks... so I'll need to get back to you on those sources.

Comment: That said, the link I already posted above is clear that "The method was to heat black magnetite ore in the presence of carbon in a sealed clay crucible inside a charcoal furnace to completely remove slag." and "from the 17th to the 19th century ...  research into wootz steel played an important role in the development of modern English, French and Russian metallurgy."

Comment: Your the one that mentioned patterned steel. Also wootz steel made the the way you mention can't be made in large amounts thus unhelpful for industrial uses, your are not making a lathe or press using wootz steel. you don't need a way ot make more kitchen knives you need iron and steel for making machinery and engines. And your source mentions three wats to make wootz steel, two of which need smelting first, with no indication if any area cast-able.

Comment: @John A few useful links for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5djVkOgu8vs <- here is a long winded explanation of wootz vs bloom steel. Despite a few minor misconceptions and obvious biases, this includes a really good description of how wootz is made, how impure it was, why it looks the way it does, and attests that it is good for casting, but comparatively poor for wrought work without further refinement.

Comment: https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-8108f508c32d5feb3704ee99b1ea4959/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-8108f508c32d5feb3704ee99b1ea4959.pdf <- here is a list of studies compiled from the 1800-1900s which details meturgists understanding of wootz impurities and applications.  While some studies showed wootz levels of contamination were detrimental, others said there was little noticeable difference and overall is seems it could be used for rails, even if it was not considered ideal.

Comment: As for pricing, yes, crucible steel is more expensive than blast furnace steel, but that's not what held back industrialization. Iron costed the equivalent of about 16USD per lb. to make even before the bessemer process was invented, but iron tools, weapons, and parts often costed the equivalent of 1000USD  or more per lb. before we could caste most things, because it had to be hammered and ground into shape.

Comment: The early industrial revolution saw advances in shaping iron/steel long before it saw mass produced steel like you are talking about. Yes, 16USD per lb is too expensive for railroads, but the OP is interested in early industrial revolution when the focus was making machines, not late revolution when you see steel as a construction material.  If you are just using steel to mechanize, then buying a few hundred lb of caste iron/steel parts is affordable, even without a blast furnace.

Comment: Except that is a catch 22 you need coke to make large amounts of cast iron, unless you have countries worth of forests to cut down, you can't buy steel parts if people can't make cast-able steel. You can't just buy steel melt it and cast it, melting it again changes its properties. I never mentioned pricing, its about the ability to make the necessary tools

Comment: @John the 1st problem I think is that you are not differentiating the early and late industrial revolution.  Early industrial revolution saw nations like England and the US making steel on the order of 10s of thousands of tons a year before the inventions of the Bessemer process or coke.  This was mass production compared to the medieval period.  By the late industrial revolution (or 2nd industrial revolution as its sometimes called) these numbers vastly increased to the millions of tons, but the OP is asking about a transitional industrial society, not a mature industrial society.

Comment: Point being that charcoal alone COULD answer this question, at-least for the 1st 100 years or so.  Coke helped the 2nd industrial revolution happen because there were not enough trees to meet demand, but the 2nd industrial revolution did not have crude oil until near the very end. If you only use charcoal as the carbonizing element, an economy that can otherwise produce 10,000 tons a year from charcoal can make over 8 million tons by using crude oil as the heat source

Comment: They most certainly had crude oil, crude oil has be utilized by humans for many centuries, what you means is there was little industrial usage, But there is no reason to suspect this would be true without oil, the industrial refining of oil has bee done since the 1740's,(Ukhta) and smaller scale refining of crude oil has been done since the romans, without coal I doubt they would ignore such a abundant fuel source.

Comment: @John Yes, I just meant that they did use it for much. Yes, oil refining vastly predates the industrial revolution, it just was not a preferred fuel source for anything because it is hard to extract and refine in significant quantities without an existing industrial infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to using coal as a source of carbon when steel was made, trees used to be used. Logs were added into the molten metal. When the supply of trees could not be sustained coal started to be used.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?